# How to open youtube video in app?

Tags: ios, swift, youtube

I would like to play youtube video in my app. But I want to open a video to full screen by image(button) clicking. I don't want to create UIWebview. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use this pod: [XCDYouTubeKit](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit).

```
func StartVideo() {

        let ViodeoViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        self.present(ViodeoViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        XCDYouTubeClient.default().getVideoWithIdentifier("KHIJmehK5OA") { (video: XCDYouTubeVideo?, error: Error?) in
            if let streamURL = video?.streamURLs[XCDYouTubeVideoQuality.HD720.rawValue] {
                ViodeoViewController.player = AVPlayer(url: streamURL)
            } else {
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
}
```

you can also change other configurations setting with the help of library.

Comment: What playerViewController is it?

Comment: @NaberApp it was ViodeoViewController i just forgot change name cuz it was code from my existing project :)

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below links:

This is helper provided by youtube, you can install this pod and can use second link to understand how to integrate in your app

https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

Comment: did you try using the library ?